# puppeteer When use headless false

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chromium

I have a script the parse a specific webpage.
When I set headless false, the puppeteer doesn't load page

```
 await page.goto('https://www.google.com', {
            waitUntil: 'load',
            // Remove the timeout
            timeout: 0
        });
```

I tried with a lot of configurations, like:

```
 const args = [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--enable-logging',
        ' --v=1',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-extension',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-infobars',
        '--window-position=0,0',
        '--ignore-certifcate-errors',
        '--ignore-certifcate-errors-spki-list',
        '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3312.0 Safari/537.36"'
    ];



    const options = {
        args,
        headless: false, // default is true
        userDataDir: "./user_data",
        defaultViewport: null,
        devtools: true,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    };
```

But the script stops to `await page.goto` until timeout.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you're parsing not the `google.com` page.
The first thing that should be considered it's the `waitUntil: 'load'`. What it done, it considers navigation to be finished when the load event is fired.

The load event is fired when the whole webpage (HTML) has loaded fully, including all dependent resources such as JavaScript files, CSS files, and images.

There is a big chance that this event is not firing in your case for a reasonable timeout, so I would suggest not to rely on this `waitUntil` but use another wait like the presence of some selector, for example

```
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
await page.waitForSelector('[name="q"]');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have the same issue, the page doesn't load

Comment: You mean that on your environment even `await page.goto('https://www.google.com')` fails with timeout error on navigation?

Comment: console.log("0")
await page.goto('https://www.google.com')
console.log("1")

I Can See just console.log("0"). How can I have a log?

Comment: What versions of puppeteer and chrome do you have? Do you really have such old chrome version as you specified in the user-agent? Also, can you say what is the HeadlessChrome version? Just `console.log(await page.browser().version());` before opening the page. There is a chance that it can be a compatibility issue https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md

Comment: HeadlessChrome/86.0.4240.0

Comment: Did you try to get the browser console logs and make a screenshot after the navigation timeout failure? Maybe they can help you to see something, just wrap the navigation with try-catch and perform some actions.

Comment: Thanks for your time.
If I use try catch, I can see TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Comment: Yes, but have you tried to get some screenshot or console logs after ignoring this exception?

Comment: Yes the code stops.it doesn't log anymore until the timeout, or restart application because it uses a lot of memory.